# System.Windows.Forms.dll got corrupted. What should I do?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I just got the error all of sudden:

> Error 1 Metadata file 'C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Windows.Forms.dll' could not be opened -- 'File is corrupt.'

What do I do?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the .NET framework?

Comment: Same problem.  Unfortunately their corruption was wide spread and required a new HDD and copy of windows. http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/236980/Windows-partly-corrupted

Comment: Why would you buy a new HDD? Just format it.

Answer (score 0):

The reference assemblies are empty placeholder assemblies installed with visual studio that are used during compilation.

Try repairing visual studio.